# Select all records where instance does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that shows me all IDs that do not have a primary value of True

[image]

For these results the query should return just 2 and 5 as those are the only ID's with only FALSE primary values

Comment: and what about 6?

Comment: Please post sample data in a consumable format. Pictures are nearly worthless here. We can't code against them.

Comment: What have you tried so far????  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361481/57475)

Comment: On a sidenote: You shouldn't call a column ID that is not the table's ID uniquely identifying a record.

Comment: A thought occurs: Is there a master table holding one record per ID? If so: is it guanranteed that every ID is also present in the table you are showing? Or can there be IDs missing from it? If so, shall the query return these IDs that are missing in your table or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
select id
from your_table t1
where not exists (select 1 
          from your_table t2
          where t2.id = t1.id and t2.primary = 'TRUE')
```

I'm assuming that the `primary` is a `varchar`

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate per ID and see whether the maximum value is 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'. As 'TRUE' > 'FALSE' in the alphabet: if max = 'FALSE' then there is no 'TRUE' record for the ID.

```
select id 
from mytable
group by id
having max(primary) = 'FALSE';
```

Of course other conditions are possible, e.g.

```
having count(case when primary = 'TRUE' then 1 end) = 0;
```